# Cannot connect to Oracle database during Visual Studio debugging

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

I am having an issue connecting to an Oracle database when running an SSIS package in debugging mode in Visual Studio. I am using Visual Studio 2012 with Data Tools installed and an Oracle 10g client.

I am using the Oracle Provider for OLE DB that came with the 10g client. I can create a Connection Manager connection to the server and test connectivity fine. I can also preview the data from my query in the OLE DB Source editor. It only fails to connect during debugging.

The actual error message is:

```
Error: 0xC0202009 at TW_Billing, Connection manager "server.schema": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified".
Error: 0xC020801C at Data Flow Task, ERDB Billing45 Source [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "server.schema" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: ERDB Billing45 Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
```

Most of the research I have done on this issue points to a 32bit error. I tried setting the ForcedExecutionMode to Int32 and ForceExecutionMode to True. I also changed the project properties to Run64bitRuntime to False. Neither of these made a difference.

If it makes a difference, we are using LDAP for Oracle connections. That said, I usually dont have an issue connecting to the TNS Names server (I.E. I can connect to the Oracle server any which way other than in Visual Studio debugging mode).

Comment: Why not use the [Oracle Managed Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/)?

Comment: Do you switch to "x86" while debugging? I.e. is it working for 64 bit?

Comment: I did. See my answer below. I was missing the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I apparently failed to install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index-097110.html

Installing this in a new Oracle Home location and re-starting Visual Studio solved my issue. Packages now run during debugging correctly.